# Outlook VBA - Replace text depending on date

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a code that will replace a placeholder text depending on the date.
These emails have to be sent in relation to reports that are generated on specific dates each month (7th, 14th, 21st and 28th). I have code in place to replace placeholder text, I just can't figure out how to determine the date that will be used (Eg; Please provide the report for #DATE#)

If the current day of the month is on or after the 7th day of the month but before the 14th, then I want the date to date to change to the 7th day of the current month. (eg; Please provide the report for 7th June 2016).

If the current day of the month is on or after the 28th day of the month but before the 7th of the next month, then I want the date to date to change to the 28th day of the that month. (eg; Please provide the report for 28th June 2016), etc.

I've been trying to use if statements and putting the current date day into a string but that doesn't work.

```
Date1 = Format(Date, "dd")

If Date1 >= 7 And Date1 <= 13 Then
Date2 = "7th"
Else

If Date1 >= 14 And Date1 <= 20 Then
Date2 = "14th"
Else

If Date1 >= 21 And Date1 <= 27 Then
Date2 = "21st"
Else
End If

If Date1 >= 28 And Date1 <= 31 Then
Date2 = "28th"
Else

If Date1 >= 1 And Date1 <= 6 Then
Date2 = "28th"
Else

End If
End If
End If
End If

obj.Subject = Replace(obj.Subject, "#DATE#", Date2)
obj.HTMLBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, "#DATE#", Date2)
```

Is anyone able to provide any assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()

Date1 = Format(Date, "dd")
curMonth = Format(Now, "mmmm yyyy")

Select Case Date1
    Case Is >= 28
        Date2 = "28th " & curMonth
    Case Is >= 21
        Date2 = "21st " & curMonth
    Case Is >= 14
        Date2 = "14th " & curMonth
    Case Is >= 7
        Date2 = "7th " & curMonth
    Case Else
        Date2 = "28th " & Format(Now - 7, "mmmm yyyy")
End Select

End Sub
```